# Why does the date output look like this(the difference between expected and real results are a hour)?

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand how to substract hours from date. I've created a method to do this.

```
public static long addHoursToDate(String dateStr, int hours) throws ParseException {
    final Calendar   result           = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    Date             date             = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateStr);
    result.setTime(date);
    result.add(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
    return result.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Below is how I use this method

```
final long expectedResultInMillis = 1328072399000L;
    final long resultInMillis = addHoursToDate("2012-01-31 22:59:59.999+0300", 10);
    if (expectedResultInMillis != resultInMillis) {
        System.out.println("Unexpected result received in addHoursToDate method: " + resultInMillis);
    }
```

I want to check that my method works correctly. So I writed some code to check.
I use site - "https://currentmillis.com/" to get expectedResultInMillis. My parameters on this site are local timezone (UTC+3h) Moscow Standard, 2012/02/01 08:59:59. The result from this site is 1328072399000.
The result from my method(resultInMillis) is 1328075999999. If I use the resultInMillis on the site, I'll get Wed Feb 01 2012 09:59:59(local time and date). It looks like the difference is a hour.

Why are expectedResultInMillis and resultInMillis different?
Could you please help?

Thanks, Alexey

Comment: `date --date='TZ="UTC+3" 2012-02-01 08:59:59.999' +%s` returns `1328097599`, so maybe `expectedResultInMillis` is wrong. Try different site to get `expectedResultInMillis`.

Comment: @ymonad I am pretty sure you are right, it is the website that is wrong.

Comment: It appears that "2012-01-31 22:59:59.999" in timezone of "Europe/Moscow" is 4 hours ahead of UTC. Try the following: `ZonedDateTime.of(2012, 1, 31, 22, 59, 59, 999000000, ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow")`

Comment: @ymonad, thanks. I've tried "https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html". On this site timestamp is 1328072399.